# Cannot set CORSEnabled and CORSTrustedOrigins properties on ADFS 2019

Tags: adfs, cors, windows-server-2019

### The Problem:

There are properties in ADFS 2019 that indicate that you can enable CORS Headers for the ADFS Login Page and set the allowed origins.

```
Get-AdfsProperties

CORSEnabled                                : False
CORSTrustedOrigins                         :
```

But the corresponding `Set-AdfsProperties` lists no switches to actually set these properties.

So here's the question. How does one manage to set these properties?

### Full disclosure:

I manage to actually set these two options by connecting to the WID via SSMS and dumping the XML that hold the properties from the `ServiceSettings` table, changing the appropriate properties, and then updating the XML in the WID.

```
Get-AdfsProperties

CORSEnabled                                : True
CORSTrustedOrigins                         : {https://localhost:5001, https://localhost:8081}
```

It works. Which is ok for my testing purposes but in no way ok for the CI/CD environment I'm currently in the process of setting up that needs to automatically add and remove values from the  `CORSTrustedOrigins` property.

### Additional information:

These properties are new in ADFS 2019, ADFS 4.0 didn't support CORS and the only way to get that running is by putting a reverse proxy in front of it to put the proper CORS Headers in the response.

I am currently trying that solution but I'm running into problems there as well. But that's nothing for this question.

### Edit 1:

So because I'm an inquisitive developer I started to use dotPeak on the `Microsoft.IdentityServer.Management` components that contain the `Set-AdfsProperties` cmdlet and I made an interesting find. There is no implementation to set the `CORSEnabled` and `CORSTrustedOrigins` as well as there seem to be methods to add custom headers to the responses which aren't implemented in the cmdlet as well.

So there basically isn't a way to actually use these advertised features. Except going into the Database to change the XML directly. Which looks to me like a bit of an oversight.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just in case anyone else is looking for it you can set it with the `Set-AdfsResponseHeaders` powershell command

```
Set-AdfsResponseHeaders -EnableCORS $true
Set-AdfsResponseHeaders -CORSTrustedOrigins http://localhost, https://contoso.com
Get-AdfsProperties | select EnableCORS, CORSTrustedOrigins
```

Comment: Is this also available on Web Application Proxy 2019?

Comment: To me it seems that this configuration has no affect when ADFS is behind WAP. I would be delighted to be proven wrong though.